# Variable loses the assigned value in Protractor test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I am running a protractor test that should check whether a record lives in the grid with a specific licence number. However after going through all the rows it loses the assigned value to the `rowNumber` variable. Not sure why it's doing that. `rowNumber` should equal to the index.

This is my test.

```
var rowNumber = null;
var rows = element.all(by.repeater('(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index'));

it('should find row the created Driver Licence lives on', function() {
    rows.each(function(element, index) {
        element.getText().then(function (text) {
            if (text.includes(licenceNumber)) {
                rowNumber = index;    //rowNumber does equal the index at this point
                return true;
            }
        });
        expect(rowNumber).not.toEqual(null);
    });

});
```

Comment: The expect is being executed before rows.each but how do I make it other way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got around it. This is what I did

```
it('should find row the created Driver Licence lives on', function() {
    rows.each(function(element, index) {
        element.getText().then(function (text) {
            if (text.includes(licenceNumber)) {
                rowNumber = index;
                return true;
            }
        }).then(function() {
            expect(rowNumber).not.toEqual(null);
        });
    });
});
```